# How to trigger @onclick within RenderFragment Antd Blazor

Tags: c#, .net-core, antd, .net-5, ant-design-blazor

I'm using ant design blazor (.net 5.0, antblazor 0.7.4) and try to trigger @onclick the Button render by RenderFragment: App.razor

```
   @inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" PreferExactMatches="@true">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(BasicLayout)" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(BasicLayout)">
            <Result Status="404"
                    Title="404"
                    SubTitle="Sorry, the page you visited does not exist."
                    Extra="extra" />
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
<AntContainer />
@code
{ 
    private void NavigateToHome()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
    }
    RenderFragment extra =@<Button Type="primary" @onclick="NavigateToHome">Back Home</Button>;

}
```

But get error:
[screen error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/of31C.png)

How to resolve this ? Tks a lots!

Comment: Add relevant tags (language, framework, library) to make your question more visible to the community

Answer (score 1):

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" PreferExactMatches="@true">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(BasicLayout)" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(BasicLayout)">
            <Result Status="404"
                    Title="404"
                    SubTitle="Sorry, the page you visited does not exist."
                    Extra="HomeButton(NavigateToHome)" />
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
<AntContainer />
@code
{ 
    private void NavigateToHome()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
    }
    RenderFragment HomeButton(Action clickAction) => @<Button Type="primary" @onclick="@clickAction">Back Home</Button>;

}
```